# Make toolbar to collapse to a fixed height

Tags: android, material-design

How can I prevent collapsible toolbar from collapsing till very end.Currently the image collapses to toolbar(48 dp), I want the image to collapse till a specific height let's say 140dp(if initial size is 200 dp)